# The limit of an infinite product involving the squares of $\binom{n}{j}x^j(1-x)^{n-j}/k$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients, infinite-product, equidistribution

Some months ago, me and a friend tried to solve the following
$"~natural~"$ question:

Given weights $p_{1},\ldots,p_{m}$ and distinct points in
$S_{0} := \left\{\, x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\,\right\}$ of ${\mathbb R}^{k}$, we constructed sets $\left(\, S_{n}\,\right)_{\, n\ \in\ {\mathbb N}}$ recursively, so that $S_{n}$ contains all possible weighted means of $S_{n - 1}$.

It turned out that $\lim S_{n}$ is dense in the convex hull of $S_{0}$, provided that $n,m \ge 2$.

At point, we asked about a stronger property, the equidistribution, and the following limit is related to such question$\ldots$, being an application of Levy's continuity theorem.

Given a irrational number $x \in \left(\, 0,1\,\right)$, show that

$$
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\prod_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\ \prod_{0\ \le\ j\le n}
\left\{\, 1 -
\left[\,
{{n \choose j}\,{x^{j}\left(\, 1 - x\,\right)^{n - j} \over k}}
\,\right]^{\,2}
\,\right\}\ =\ 0
$$

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're interested in this limit?  What does irrationality of $x$ have to do with it?

Comment: Yes, the particular reason why I am interested in this limit is that it is related to the equidistribution of iterated means in the convex hull of some distinct point; here $x$ and $1-x$ represent the "weight" to calculate the means. But I don't get why it had three consecutive downvotes

Comment: It might have helped if you had stated that, rather than just asking an apparently random question.

Comment: I will take it in mind next time, thank you Robert

Answer (score 1):

Interchange the two products.

$$ \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1 - p^2/k^2) = \dfrac{\sin(\pi p)}{\pi p} $$

So you're asking about the limit as $n \to \infty$ of

$$ \prod_{j=0}^n \dfrac{\sin(\pi p_j(n))}{\pi p_j(n)} $$
where $p_j(n) = {n \choose j} x^j (1-x)^{n-j}$.
Note that $\sin(t)/t =  1 - t^2/6 + O(t^4) = \exp(-t^2/6 + O(t^4))$.
Now $p_j(n) = P(X=j)$ where $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $x$.  The logarithm of your product is thus approximately
$$ -\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}  \sum_{j=0}^n p_j(n)^2 $$
But since $0 < p_j(n) < 1$ and $\sum_{j=0}^n p_j(n) = 1$ we have
$$ -\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}  \sum_{j=0}^n p_j(n)^2 \ge - \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$
So I don't believe your limit can be $0$.

Comment: A great answer, thanks Robert. On the other hand, i am quite surprised, a lot of "simple" sequences are not equidistributed, but i wasn't expecting this